# Toolbar Action Button Icon color

Tags: android, android-toolbar, aide-ide

I am using the `appcompat-v7 toolbar` and added some menu with icons.

My `menu_items.xml`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/quit"
    android:title="Quit"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_power"
    android:orderInCategory="700"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="600"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_cog"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:orderInCategory="500"
    android:title="Help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:orderInCategory="400"
    android:title="Logout"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/tip"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:title="Give Tip"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_coffee"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/withdraw"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="Withdraw"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_bank"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/deposit"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Deposit"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_cash_multiple"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

The icons are originally black but i was expecting it to appear as white on the toolbar if I use the

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

Instead it shows black icons.
[image: black icons]

My toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

How can I make the icons appear white?

Edit:

The icons shown on the toolbar are the only icons i want to change color.. Not all the icons, including the overflowed item's icon...
[image: overflow items]

Comment: Why downvote? I searched for 5 hours just to find answer to this question before posting here..

Comment: Why cant you just make the icon images white? It's so much simpler.

Comment: Did you have any non-programmatic solutions?

Answer (score 6):

you can set manually like this

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
            Drawable drawable = menu.getItem(i).getIcon();
            if(drawable != null) {
                drawable.mutate();
                drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

for particular icon:

```
MenuItem favoriteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite);
Drawable newIcon = (Drawable)favoriteItem.getIcon();
newIcon.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 200, 200, 200), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
favoriteItem.setIcon(newIcon);
```

if your orientation changing runtime then you can check orientation using condition and set menu color in this condition.

like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       // here you can set menu item color if it landScape

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
    }
}
```

or if you dont want to rotate your screen, you can simply set in manifest file like this:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

or you can use itemIconTint for particular items:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/quit"
    android:title="Quit"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_power"
    android:orderInCategory="700"
    **app:itemIconTint="@color/black"**
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="600"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_cog"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    **app:itemIconTint="@color/black"**
    android:title="Settings"/>
```

Comment: Will this change the overflow icons also? Coz I have icons on the overflow menu.

Comment: yes.. it will change, just copy this code.. and you will know.

Comment: I just tried it and it does change the overflow icons also.. I want only the shown action button icons to change color but not the overflown menu icons.

Comment: then you can select perticular icon in for loop and set drawable to this icon..  its simple solution..

Comment: i hope you get it.. right.., and approve my answer if it is helpful

Comment: now you can see my updated answer, and you can also apply iconTint in your menu.xml

Comment: But how will that know what items are shown in the toolbar? When Screen is rotated or screen size changed the displayed items will vary.. Although this is a good work arround, it does not achieve what I want

Comment: now again look my updated answer.. maybe now you can able to achieve your goal.

Answer (score -1):

**Your Main theme**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
   </style>
```

> **PopUp or menu item theme also if you want some more like background of popup ,size and popupmenu you can add if you want otherwise remove**

```
    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">9sp</item>


    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small</item>
    </style>
```

**Color**

```
  <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
```

Comment: The popupMenu is ok .. Only the icons on the Toolbar that i want to set the color...